# p2p sockets table

Tags: sockets, tcp, p2p

I'm creating a socket table from a network composed of 2 hosts. They have a p2p connection and they're working with tcp protocol. Do I have to create a welcoming socket in both of the hosts (as they act like servers)? And a receiving socket as well as a sending socket for each host? Or just one for sending/receiving would be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each host will need a listening socket on which it will accept new connections. It will also need one socket for each inbound TCP connection (returned from the `accept` call when it accepts an inbound connection) and one for each outbound TCP connection (returned from the `socket` call before calling `connect` to make the outbound connection).